# Pandas groupby two columns and expand the third

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
A       B       C
a       b       1
a       b       2
a       b       3
c       d       7
c       d       8
c       d       5
c       d       6
c       d       3
e       b       4
e       b       3
e       b       2
e       b       1
```

And I will like to transform it into this:

```
A       B       C1      C2      C3      C4      C5
a       b       1       2       3       NAN     NAN
c       d       7       8       5       6       3
e       b       4       3       2       1       NAN
```

In other words, something like groupby A and B and expand C into different columns.

Knowing that the length of each group is different.

C is already ordered

Shorter groups can have NAN or NULL values (empty), it does not matter.

Comment: Don't put a solution in the question. I've removed it for you. Normally, you'd [post your own answer](/help/self-answer) instead, but where this change is so minor, it'd be better to [suggest an edit on the answer](/posts/74401567/edit).

Comment: @wjandrea, in the future, please, refrain from erasing the most correct solution. You are wasting everybody's time, including yours.

Comment: IMO, it's fundamentally the same as the accepted solution, so it doesn't require its own answer. (And I assume anyone getting the warning could solve it themselves.) In any case, it's important to separate questions and answers because of the format of this site: problems up top, solutions below. Others have said the same thing, like here's [a mod's take on a vaguely similar situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267437/4518341).

Comment: Right now, it is essentially the same. But the deprecation warning means that in the future the accepted solution will not work anymore. Therefore, you are making future coders wasting their time by erasing the correct solution.

Comment: It'll still be fundamentally the same since it's only a minor part that changes. We also have answers on this site written for Python 2 that still use `print` as a statement instead of a function and all you need to do to make them work in Python 3 is add parentheses. Although, editing them to add the parentheses is perfectly fine, and that's just like what I'm suggesting here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`pandas.Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with 1, to start naming the new columns from 1 onwards, then pass this to [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), and add [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to rename the columns (C1, C2, C3, etc...). Finally use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to remove the indexes original name ('g') and transform the `MultiIndex` into columns by using [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)columns `A,B`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount().add(1)

df = df.pivot(['A','B'], 'g', 'C').add_prefix('C').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
print (df)
   A  B   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
0  a  b  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  c  d  7.0  8.0  5.0  6.0  3.0
2  e  b  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
```

Because `NaN` is by default of type float, if you need the columns dtype to be integers add [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) with `Int64`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount().add(1)

df = (df.pivot(['A','B'], 'g', 'C')
        .add_prefix('C')
        .astype('Int64')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   A  B  C1  C2  C3    C4    C5
0  a  b   1   2   3  <NA>  <NA>
1  c  d   7   8   5     6     3
2  e  b   4   3   2     1  <NA>
```

EDIT: If there's a maximum `N` new columns to be added, it means that `A,B` are duplicated. Therefore, it will beneeded to add helper groups `g1, g2` with integer and modulo division, adding a new level in index:

```
N = 4
g  = df.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
df['g1'], df['g2'] = g // N, (g % N) + 1
df = (df.pivot(['A','B','g1'], 'g2', 'C')
        .add_prefix('C')
        .droplevel(-1)
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   A  B   C1   C2   C3   C4
0  a  b  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
1  c  d  7.0  8.0  5.0  6.0
2  c  d  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  e  b  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more the idea behind this code?

Comment: Thanks! It almost does the trick. However, instead of producing 10 C columns (10 is the maximum length of a group), it produces a few dozens (C_1...C_3000). The numerical indexes are not correlative.

Comment: @jezrael Do you need `.rename_axis(columns=None)` ? I removed it and I think it works fine. Let me know because I would like to edit the answer slightly. It is brilliant.

Comment: @mirix - added solution to `EDIT`

Comment: @CeliusStingher - then in ouput is `g` for first solution and `g2` for EDIT solution if remove `.rename_axis(columns=None)`

Comment: Ok, but also can be added after `reset_index()` Thanks. I will edit the answer shortly if you don't mind

Comment: It works! Thanks a million! Just a little deprecation warning: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.pivot will be keyword-only.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.astype({'C':str}).groupby([*'AB'])\
    .agg(','.join).C.str.split(',',expand=True)\
    .add_prefix('C').reset_index()


 A  B C0 C1 C2    C3    C4
0  a  b  1  2  3  None  None
1  c  d  7  8  5     6     3
2  e  b  4  3  2     1  None
```

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74401567/4518341) but avoiding the deprecation warning:

```
N = 3
g  = df_grouped.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
df_grouped['g1'], df_grouped['g2'] = g // N, (g % N) + 1
df_grouped = (df_grouped.pivot(index=['A','B','g1'], columns='g2', values='C')
        .add_prefix('C_')
        .astype('Int64')
        .droplevel(-1)
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index())
```